# Get appengine account email from token

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I have a little appengine app running for me and my friends and forgot the email address I created it with (I still know the password though). While I can't log into the admin interface I still have the ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens file and can still deploy code to it from the commandline.

Is there any way to find the email address this way? I checked the documentation but I didn't find any way to programatically get the email address that owns the app. I also looked for how to get user info from the google user API with the access_token from the file but only got "invalid access" errors.

Is there anyway to find out the email address that I used to create the app based on the access_token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it IS possible to get the user email from a token but ONLY if its scopes included a scope that has access to the user email. see: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#tokeninfo-validation

however dont get excited yet as on your case its very unlikely that your token would have it unless you had specifically added a scope like userinfo.email to the scopes when you got that refresh token originally.

Comment: Damn, that's what I feared. All I have is "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" RIP app. thank you!

Comment: say bye bye app :) welcome and sorry. It would have also saved you if you shared the appengine with other users as admins. Worth looking in all your appspot.com listings.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to get an email address from an oauth token, even your own.